# How to check the version of OpenMP on windows

Tags: cygwin, version, openmp

I wonder how to check the version of OpenMP on a windows by using Cygwin64. Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenMP version is binded with the compiler. 
You need to check GCC's version in your Cygwin first.

https://www.openmp.org/resources/openmp-compilers-tools/

Answer (score 2):

The OpenMP specification says:

> In implementations that support a preprocessor, the `_OPENMP` macro name is defined to have the decimal value *yyyymm* where *yyyy* and *mm* are the year and month designations of the version of the OpenMP API that the implementation supports.

For Fortran implementations that do not support C-style preprocessing, the `integer parameter openmp_version` (provided by both `use omp_lib` and `include 'omp_lib.h'` interfaces) is set to the same *yyyymm* value.

The following table lists the correspondence between the number and the version (dates were looked up [here](http://openmp.org/wp/openmp-specifications/) and then cross-referenced with existing header files).

```
 _OPENMP | OpenMP version
---------+----------------
  200011 | 2.0 (Fortran)
  200203 | 2.0 (C/C++)
  200505 | 2.5
---------+----------------
  200805 | 3.0
  201107 | 3.5
---------+----------------
  201307 | 4.0
  201511 | 4.5
---------+----------------
```